# Erlang ets access right

Tags: erlang

I am using ets table in Erlang and comes across a question about the access right to the table. I know that the default access is protected. And if I want the non-owner processes to be able to write in  this table, I need to set the access to public.

So, my question is: 
Is there a way to grant public access to certain group of non-owner processes only?

My curet design:

Top_sup -> Sup -> WorkerA

Top_sup -> WorkerB

Comment: Have you read the ETS docs? Or considered that the owning process can receive messages?

Comment: Oh...I think you mean I can send a msg to the owner process and do the update...makes sense.

Comment: Now you're on track. Well, one of the various ones, anyway. :-) Erlang is a different want of thinking than you're probably used to. Processes are stingy with their resources; they don't share (in most cases). You have to make them be friends with one another, and *ask* them to do things. Once this becomes natural to your mind, everything will be *way* easier than you thought. It is the price of cheap concurrency.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In the Erlang world, is it normal for a supervisor to own ets tables or calling a child's function (by sending the child a msg)?

Comment: Managing ets tables is not typically something one would do with a supervisor. Usually you want supervisors to do as *little* as possible. If you are trying to manage a registry of processes try the `global` or `pg2` modules, or `gproc`. Outside of keeping track of processes (and unless you have tens of thousands, ETS is overkill anyway) supervisors shouldn't be managing data, that is *work*, which is what *workers* are for. Types of work in a system are many and varied, which is why we write *supervisor trees* instead of just one or two supervisors.

Comment: with ets, it may be also important to pay attention to ets owner crashes. There is some information here: [link](http://steve.vinoski.net/blog/2011/03/23/dont-lose-your-ets-tables/)

Comment: I have added a representation of my working design. 

@zxq9: I agree with you that supervisor should do as little as possible. Then would it be count as too much for a supervisor to send a msg to another process (Sup to WorkerB and update the ets tables there) and then restart WorkerA?

Comment: @Pascal: I have added a representation of my working design. Thanks for the link. I have thought about that. Currently in my model WorkerB and Sup both holds some ets tables. I was thinking to add their supervisors as heirs. Is it a common practice to have supervisors as ets table heir?